# How to use a table valued function in select clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I have a **tableA** with one of the string columns (**rawData**) and I have a table-valued function (**functionA**) that functions will accept '**rawData**' as an input parameter and returns five new fields. *what will that function do? - this will do some string manipulation and split some data into five values*

My motive is to select that string column (**rawData**)  and also pass that table-valued function (**functionA**) and get those five new fields for every row in  **tableA**

Here is the sample:

```
Select 
    (Select * from function (rawData))
from tableA
```

my expectations are I should get every row with that values from **functionA** along with **rawData**, but I'm getting below error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use a CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT a.rawData, b.*
FROM TableA a
CROSS APPLY FunctionA(a.rawdata) b
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first off, let's examine why you are getting an error. What is wrong with your syntax?

Well, a subquery in the `select` clause is expected to return at most one column. Your subquery, by using `*`, is returning all of the columns from the results of your function call, which appears to be more than one in this case.

Next, what are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you are trying to take the value of a column from `tableA` and apply `functionA` to the value in that column for each row returned from `tableA`.

The proper syntax to accomplish that is by using an `apply`. There is both `cross apply` and `outer apply`. The difference between them is like the difference between an `inner join` and a `left join` (or `left outer join`).

In other words, for the `cross apply`, if no rows are returned from the call to `functionA` for a particular row from `tableA`, then that row from `tableA` will not be included. For the `outer apply`, that case would be reversed, as the row from `tableA` would still be included, just the columns from the function call would be null.

An example query with this syntax based on the query in your question would be the following:

```
select fa.*
from tableA ta
outer apply functionA(ta.rawData) fa;
```

Note that I used an `outer apply` in my example, since your query didn't seem to be expecting rows from `tableA` with no rows returned from `functionA` to be excluded.